# Netscaler expression function challenge

Tags: citrix, netscaler

Trying to check if a SAML attribute contains a role retrieved from a stringmap (the attribute contains a comma separated list of roles):

`HTTP.REQ.USER.ATTRIBUTE(5).CONTAINS(HTTP.REQ.URL.QUERY.VALUE("pageid").MAP_STRING("UrlProtection"))`

Unfortunately Netscaler complains: `Only constant parameters are allowed for function ["pageid").MAP_STRING, 72]`

Any ideas how to get around this?

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking for specific group from list of groups extracted for user, you can do so using...

-searchFilter "memberOf=CN=VPNAllowed,OU=support,DC=citrix,DC=com"
-groupAttrName memberOf

For detail explanation, see

http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX111079